# How to effeciently/repeatibly prototype a web app front end?

Tags: html, css, themes, frontend

As most web development freelancers, I'm facing the problem of the front-end part of the application, doing front-end development from scratch (even using css frameworks such as 960gs or blueprint) is still just too much time consuming.

Is there a reliable/repeatable way of quickly generating a front-end prototype without relying too much on HTML/CSS editing? Can ready-made css/html templates (whether free of commercial) save time?

I can think of stuff like weebly or artisteer but these are pretty basic and the resulting code is not easily changeable.

Web frameworks like Rails and Django have pretty darn well solved the back-end problem, but the front-end thingy is still untouched in my humble opinion.

Comment: What kind of prototype ? There are tools for generating interactive wireframes fast, but I guess that is not what you want ? If you need production quality markup and css, there is really no other option than actually writing it.

Comment: This question seems pretty open-ended. It might help to nail down more closely what you are seeking, either with positive or negative examples.

Comment: driis, I agree that probably writing the damned thing is the only real option but my gut feeling is that there's gotta be a quicker/smarter way of doing at least a presentable prototype (or a gamut of prototypes) to the client before doing the heavy work of back-end integration. And btw, I'm talking mostly about CMS like apps with moderate data use. But you know CMS are pretty hard to have their themes customized. And I'm not talking about things like Twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using frameworks like [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) can speedup your development

Comment: Foundation looks very promising, I'll try it out.